# After Migration from spring boot 1.5.6 to 2.6.2 getting exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

Currently I am migrating from spring boot 1.5.6 to 2.6.2 but due to the latest version of hibernate getting class cast exception
I add "exclude=HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration" after that getting exception "Spring boot hibernate no transaction is in progress" .Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

pom.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <description> </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <io.springfox.version>3.0.0</io.springfox.version>
         
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>mdmscheldt</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

stacktrace

---

```
6:06:02,934 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder (org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder and org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder are in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.mdmscheldt.war' @322eec05)

16:06:02,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(HibernateTransactionManager.java:423)

16:06:02,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:347)

16:06:02,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)

16:06:02,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)

16:06:02,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)

16:06:02,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

16:06:02,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)

16:06:02,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.mdmscheldt.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
```

Hibernate Configuration File

---

```
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalSessionFactoryBean SessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { this.ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN });
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", this.HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", this.HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", this.HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionFactory;
}
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(this.DEV_DB_URL + "databaseName="+ DEV_DB_NAME +";");
    dataSource.setUsername(this.DEV_DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(this.DEV_DB_PASSWORD);
    return (DataSource)dataSource;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(SessionFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
......
}
```

Comment: Without more information this will be impossible to answer. Disabling JPA is obviously **not** the solution as that is what you are using.

Comment: after spring boot migration to 2.6.2 , i am getting the exception :  "org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder"

Comment: Please don't add it as comments add it to your question. Also add your dependencies (your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` and the full stacktrace).

Comment: @M.Deinum added the details in description

Comment: Why do you have a `HibernateTransactionManager` in the first place? YOu don't need that as you are using JPA which should use the `JpaTransactionManager` which is auto configured by default.

Comment: @M.Deinum In the old code the code is like below: (can u suggest how we can use JpaTransactionManager instead of HibernateTransactionManager )? @ Bean @ Primary public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() { HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(); txManager.setSessionFactory(SessionFactory().getObject()); return txManager; }

Comment: Please don't add code as comments (as mentioned before). Extend your question. Remove your transaction manager and remove the configuration of the `SessionFactory`. Just use JPA instead of the session factory.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added the some code part of my HiebrnateConfiguration  in description .Still I have confusion how to change the code as you said.

Comment: I wonder why you have this code in the first place? You are using Spirng Boot, why not use that to configure your datasource and hibernate in the first place? Seems like you are attempting to work around the framework instead of using it. For the datasource add the proper `spring.datasource` properties to your `application.properties`. For hibernate do the same using the `spring.jpa` properties. Then remove this configuration.